# remote desktop to an azure VM (created by the new portal - portal.azure.com) over the port 443

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Virtual Machine created in the new azure portal (portal.azure.com)
Now I can connect to by using the Remote Desktop by the port 3389, without any problems.

I am asking for a guide to setting my virtual machine can be remoted over the port 443 also (since the working network just allows outcoming 443 only)

With the classic portal, I just need to add an "end point" and that works.

However with the new portal, in the "network security group", I tried to modify the "inbound security rules", changed the default value 3389 to 443, but I got no luck.

Edited: captured screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is a Windows VM: Have you confirmed that port 443 isn't already being consumed by IIS?

Comment: yes, I even don't have the IIS installed. thanks, I attach an screenshot in my question.

Answer (score 1):

New VM created as "Azure Resource Manager" (ARM) have different options and features but they lost end-points. Endpoints, in classic deployment, allowed to remap internal ports to external ports, changing the value.
Now, in ARM, to have a similar behaviour, you have to use LoadBalancer. Read at the end of https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2016/02/04/azure-networking-public-ip-addresses-in-classic-vs-arm/ for an example to map external 50000 to internal 80.

Comment: @DavidMakogon perhaps I'm wrong. I understood that khoailang want to "translate" the port: internal RDP bounded to 3389 but exposed on 443 on Internet. AFAIK this is trivial with old VMs (endpoints) but tricky with new VMs (need loadbalancer). Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just as easy, but now with inbound security rules on the network security group - see my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/737796/99269).

Comment: @DavidMakogon  the comment of Pedro Perez on you answer is like mine. In the inbound security rule, where do you put external and internal TCP port values?

Comment: my comment contains a link to an answer I posted.

Comment: I attached a screenshot for the "inbound security rules"

Answer (score 1):

As I understand them, Network Security Groups don't actually do any port mapping, just allow/deny access to certain ports. If you want the RDP server to still listen on 3389 and for external RDP requests to go to 443, you'll need to use Azure Load Balancer with NAT rules (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-internet-arm-ps/#create-lb-rules-nat-rules-a-probe-and-a-load-balancer). Alternatively, you could configure your RDP server to listen on port 443. It's up to you which you prefer :).